# order of C'tors/D'tors in inheritance and exception

Tags: c++, exception

link to the screenshot of the code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCqwv.jpg

I don't understand why the Dtor of Base class activate 3 times, 
and Dtor of Derived class activate 2 times, instead 1 time for Base and for Derived?

```
#include <iostream>
class Base
{
   public:
          Base()
          {
                 cout<<"Base Ctor!\n";
          }
          ~Base()
          {
                 cout<<"Base Dtor!\n";
          }
};
class Derived : public Base
{
 public:
        Derived()
        {
                 cout<<"Derived Ctor!\n";
        }
       ~Derived()
        {
                 cout<<"Derived Dtor!\n";
        }
};

int main()
{
            Derived d;
            try
            {
             throw d;
            }
            catch (Base b)
            {
             cout<<"Caught Base Exception!\n";
            }
            catch (Derived d)
            {
             cout<<"Caught Derived Exception!\n";
            }
            return 0;
 }
```

OutPut:

```
Base Ctor!
Derived Ctor!
Caught Base Exception!
Base Dtor!
Derived Dtor!
Base Dtor!
Derived Dtor!
Base Dtor!
```

Comment: You'll probably want to implement a copy constructor.

Comment: @ThomasJager i wrote this code just for understand the flow of the throw and catch, i dont need a C.Ctor or anything else.

Comment: If you don't have one, you won't know if the object is being copied.

Comment: @ThomasJager ok, so how i implement the C.Ctor to fix the duplicates?

Comment: @ThomasJager Suppuse i declare: Derived(const Derived& other):Base(other){}  what i’m doing with the “throw” in the main function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throwing and catching makes some copy-ctor calls. Read [some info](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch).

To see how it works I've added some code to yours:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base
 {
   public:
          Base()
                {
                 cout<<"Base Ctor!\n";
                }
          ~Base()
                {
                 cout<<"Base Dtor!\n";
                }
          Base(Base& other)
                {
                 cout<<"Base Copy Ctor!\n";
                }
};
class Derived : public Base
{
 public:
        Derived()
                {
                 cout<<"Derived Ctor!\n";
                }
       ~Derived()
                {
                 cout<<"Derived Dtor!\n";
                }
       Derived(Derived& other)
                {
                 cout<<"Derived Copy Ctor!\n";
                }
};

int main()
          {
            Derived d;
            try
            {
             cout << "Before throwing d\n";
             throw d;
             cout << "After throwing d\n";
            }

            catch (Base b)
            {
             cout<<"Caught Base Exception!\n";
            }
            catch (Derived d)
            {
             cout<<"Caught Derived Exception!\n";
            }
       return 0;
 }
```

You can see it in action [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/R16kSSJWi4SuTsLc). By now ignore the warnings about unused vars. The other warnings are useful, as they suggest to call the base copy-ctor from the derived copy-ctor. Modify the code and play a bit with it.

It outputs:

```
Base Ctor!
Derived Ctor!
Before throwing d
Base Ctor!
Derived Copy Ctor!
Base Copy Ctor!
Caught Base Exception!
Base Dtor!
Derived Dtor!
Base Dtor!
Derived Dtor!
Base Dtor!
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!